# Is "In Wonderland" a new series or does it contain story-relevant plots from the main series?

Tags: once-upon-a-time, once-upon-a-time-in-wonderland

I'm currently watching *Once Upon A Time* again, as a new season for me has been released. I am aware that there is a spin-off series calles *Once Upon A Time In Wonderland*, but I'm not sure when this spon-off hooks in.

As I'm scared of spoilers I won't look on the interwebs. I'm looking this series with my girlfriend and it's a total tension breaker when one knows what will happen and the other not.

**So does "In Wonderland" contain plots that may be relevant to the main series?** Like one re-occuring character that made something up, which then is important in a new season in the main series?

Or maybe in other words: **Is there a specific time when I should watch "In Wonderland" first instead of continueing with the main series?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Once Upon A Time in Wonderland* is a *almost* entirely stand-alone spin-off of *Once Upon A Time*. There's nothing in the plot of any of the *Wonderland* episodes that impacts the main show, or vice versa.

If you're going to watch *Wonderland*, the only thing I'd recommend is that you do it between seasons 3 and 4 of *Once Upon A Time*. The only reason this matters (and it's rather small) is because of the Will Scarlett, aka the Knave of Hearts. He's one of the lead characters in *Wonderland*, and after that show was cancelled, he was made a series regular in *Once Upon A Time*. He shows up early in Season 4 as as one of Robin Hood's men. To my knowledge, we never get more than passing references to the things he did in Wonderland. None of the other characters or events have even been mentioned in the main show (so far.)

---

Purely my opinion but: *Wonderland* wasn't a terrible show, but you wouldn't miss anything by just skipping it entirely. If you're looking for another *Once Upon A Time*, that's not it. It's a much more formulaic story, basically a mash-up of Alice in Wonderland and Aladdin. I'm a huge OUAT fan and I don't think I watched the last few episodes of *Wonderland*.

Answer (score -1):

Wrong wonderland and se3 of storybook do have info relevant to both shows. The crossovers are hard to spot

Plus the characters and story lines from both shows are intertwined so this is the order you need to watch it in 
Seasons 1+2 ouat
Alternate season 3 ouat and wonderland episodes
The watch season 4 where wonderland story starts being interested.

The reason for this is the same reason for the show success they hide little things details and hints to what the future has to hold like runic writing in both shows

We need to remember this is not an ABC production really
It is Disney 
Which we all know has a magical ability to tell one story on the surface while other stories being told deep below the surface

Comment: I watched all of Season 3 of OuaT and almost all of Wonderland and I don't remember a single case where the storylines intertwined; can you give some examples?

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield The Knave of Hearts is probably the biggest crossover.  Wonderland was also the first hint we had that the laws of magic can be broken under certain circumstances.  I don't think there were storyline crossovers though?

Comment: @izkata but the knave of hearts didn't show up in storybrooke until S4, after Wonderland was cancelled, so I can't see why that's a good reason to alternate watching episodes of the two shows as this answer claims. That's what I'm trying to get clarification on

Comment: Plus "little hidden hints" are not "story-relevant plots". It's often even just an easter-egg for fans of both shows. May you please clarify in your answer why I should watch it in your order? What would I miss / get spoilered?